# Do not show up the bootstrap icon even import BIcon

Tags: vue.js, icons, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

In my nuxt.js bootstrap-vue project:

I follow github to use bootstrap icon:
[the link](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/5280#issuecomment-621689373)

my code:

```
      <b-icon variant="success" icon="arrow-up"></b-icon>
      <b-icon variant="success" icon="alert-triangle"></b-icon>

      <b-icon icon="alert-circle-fill" variant="success"></b-icon>

      <h2 class="group_title">Anime Wallpapers</h2>

...

<script>

  import { BIcon, BIconArrowUp } from 'bootstrap-vue'

  export default{
    data(){
      return {
        msg: 'hello vue'
      }
    },
    components: {
      BIcon
    }
  }
</script>
```

but there do not shows up it:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You imported `BIcon` and registered it, but you didn't register the requested individual icons.

try this:

```html
      <b-icon variant="success" icon="arrow-up"></b-icon>

      <b-icon icon="alert-circle-fill" variant="success"></b-icon>

      <h2 class="group_title">Anime Wallpapers</h2>

...

<script>

  import { BIcon, BIconArrowUp } from 'bootstrap-vue'

  export default{
    data(){
      return {
        msg: 'hello vue'
      }
    },
    components: {
      BIcon,
      BIconArrowUp // <- The icon needs to be registered with your page/app
    }
  }
</script>
```

Refer to the docs that mention that you need to import individual icons: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/icons#usage

Comment: I have similar problem but am importing and registering the individual icon components globally.  `import { BIcon, BIconPersonCircle } from 'bootstrap-vue'`, `Vue.component(BIcon)`, `Vue.component(BIconPersonCircle)`.  And in template,  `<b-icon icon="person-circle"></b-icon>` but the icon isn't rendered.  Any idea why? Thanks

Comment: Found the answer to my question.  Just in case anyone else has the same situation.  You will have to give a name when globally registering the individual icon like `Vue.component("BIcon", BIcon)`.